# How to put enctype="multipart/form-data" in categories form?

Tags: categories, custom-field

I had success putting the code below to include enctype (for images) in custom post type forms, but I'm not able to use it in categories form... is this possible?
Thanks.

```
add_action( 'post_edit_form_tag' , 'post_edit_form_tag' );

function post_edit_form_tag( ) {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the $taxonomy_term_edit_form_tag action.

```
function add_post_enctype() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
add_action( 'category_term_edit_form_tag' , 'add_post_enctype' );
```